# Using Imports-Loader and Exports-Loader at same time for legacy code

Tags: webpack-2, imports-loader, exports-loader

I have 2 legacy JS files, which I do not want to change. For that reason I want to use exports-loader and imports-loader

File B-legacy needs the global var *GLOB* from File A-legacy

My webpack.config.js results in

```
rules: [
        { test: /\.ts$/, use: 'ts-loader' },     // Typescript file loader;              
        {
            test: path.resolve(__dirname, '../Scripts/legacy/A-legacy'),        
            use: 'exports-loader?GLOB'
        },
        {
            test: path.resolve(__dirname, '../Scripts/legacy/B-legacy'),
            use: 'imports-loader?GLOB'
        } 
    ],
```

For my understanding that should work. I'm exporting the GLOB var in A-legacy and want to import it to B-legacy.

But building it gives the following error:

> ERROR in ./Scripts/legacy/B-legacy.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'GLOB' in 'C:\anypath\Scripts\legacy'
>    @ ./Scripts/legacy/A-legacy.js 2:11-26

I've already tried to add enforce: "pre" to exports-loader rule. But that doesn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

Had exactly same error in my setup, although I am using inline imports. The way I have solved the problem was by removing `imports-loader` for `B-legacy` file.

Example setup were I was getting `Module not found` error:

```
import formValidation from 'exports-loader?FormValidation!./src/form-validation';
import script from '!!imports-loader?$=jquery,FormValidation!./src/script';
```

Fixed setup:

```
import formValidation from 'exports-loader?FormValidation!./src/form-validation';
import script from '!!imports-loader?$=jquery!./src/script'; // removed FormValidation
```

On top of this, I had to expose `FormValidation` so it is still available in the browser and use `imports-loader` to define `this` as `window`:

```
import formValidation from 'expose-loader?FormValidation!imports-loader?this=>window!exports-loader?FormValidation!./src/form-validation';
```

**Note that order of loaders is important.**